# Spring Data JPA data duplication

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following project structure:

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<TaskCard> taskCards;
}

public class TaskCard {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "taskCard", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Task> tasks;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}

public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;  

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_card_id")
    private TaskCard taskCard;
}
```

And the problem consists here in what. When accessing the POST Task Controller method to create a new task I do the following:

```
@PostMapping
public Task createTask(@CurrentUser UserPrincipal userPrincipal, @PathVariable("cardId") Long cardId, @RequestBody Task task) {
    User user = userService.findUserById(userPrincipal.getId());
    task.setTaskCard(user.getTaskCards().stream()
                         .filter(card -> card.getId().equals(cardId))
                         .findFirst()
                         .get());
    return taskService.saveTask(task);
}
```

User Principal is the current user. But it just stores metadata and I take the id from it to find it in the user's database. Here it is worth noting that I am looking for a user in the database and from it I get taskcards and look for the desired card. After that, I assign this value to the new tosk so that it belongs to this card. After that, I save it in the repository. But the problem is that after this, another identical card is created for the User instance, so every time I add a task, I get another copy of the task cards that are in the user. The problem is that I have no idea how they get there or how they are saved. In the database, I have everything in order, the data is not duplicated, but why then when extracting from the database, I do not get the cards that have 'user_id' equal to this user, but everything in a row along with duplicates? It even sounds incomprehensible. I attach screenshots of what my database looks like:

**This is users**
[image]

**This is task cards**

[image]

**This is tasks**

[image]

As you can see in the database everything is in order, there is no duplication, but here's what happens in debug:
[image]

I added 5 tasks and in the end I got 5 duplicates of the card, although it should only be one. As you can see, the whole problem is in the "local" user instance, which stores duplicates. How do I fix this?

Comment: What does the method `taskService.saveTask(task)` do? And what do you mean by "when extracting from the database"? How are you querying the data?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably join fetching the collections and this is what can happen when you use a `List` in your model. I suggest you use a `Set` instead i.e. `private Set<Task> tasks;`